# Creating an expanding CCSprite cluster

Tags: optimization, c, objective-c, ios

I am creating an "explosion" of circle sprites from the character with this code, and I was wondering if there is a more effective way to do such things, because this just seems too stupid. 
(This is cocos2d)

```
int tileSize = 29;
explosionLenght += 1;
if (explosionLenght >= 7)
{
    explosionLenght = 1;
}

CCSprite *circle0 = [[CCSprite alloc]initWithFile:@"Circle.png"];
CCSprite *circle1 = [[CCSprite alloc]initWithFile:@"Circle.png"];
CCSprite *circle2 = [[CCSprite alloc]initWithFile:@"Circle.png"];
CCSprite *circle3 = [[CCSprite alloc]initWithFile:@"Circle.png"];
CCSprite *circle4 = [[CCSprite alloc]initWithFile:@"Circle.png"];




CGPoint circle0position = ccp(_cat.position.x , _cat.position.y);
CGPoint circle1position = ccp(_cat.position.x - tileSize , _cat.position.y);
CGPoint circle2position = ccp(_cat.position.x + tileSize , _cat.position.y);
CGPoint circle3position = ccp(_cat.position.x  , _cat.position.y -tileSize);
CGPoint circle4position = ccp(_cat.position.x  , _cat.position.y + tileSize);

CGPoint c0TileCoordt = [self tileCoordForPosition:circle0position];
CGPoint c1TileCoordt = [self tileCoordForPosition:circle1position];
CGPoint c2TileCoordt = [self tileCoordForPosition:circle2position];
CGPoint c3TileCoordt = [self tileCoordForPosition:circle3position];
CGPoint c4TileCoordt = [self tileCoordForPosition:circle4position];

CGPoint c0TileCoord = [self positionForTileCoord:c0TileCoordt];
CGPoint c1TileCoord = [self positionForTileCoord:c1TileCoordt];
CGPoint c2TileCoord = [self positionForTileCoord:c2TileCoordt];
CGPoint c3TileCoord = [self positionForTileCoord:c3TileCoordt];
CGPoint c4TileCoord = [self positionForTileCoord:c4TileCoordt];

circle0.position = c0TileCoord;
circle1.position = c1TileCoord;
circle2.position = c2TileCoord;
circle3.position = c3TileCoord;
circle4.position = c4TileCoord;

CGPoint centreTileCoord = ccp(circle0.position.x, circle0.position.y);
CGPoint leftTileCoord = ccp(circle1.position.x, circle1.position.y);
CGPoint bottomTileCoord = ccp(circle3.position.x, circle3.position.y);
CGPoint rightTileCoord = ccp(circle2.position.x, circle2.position.y);
CGPoint topTileCoord = ccp(circle4.position.x, circle4.position.y);

CGPoint cTileCoord = [self tileCoordForPosition:centreTileCoord];
CGPoint lTileCoord = [self tileCoordForPosition:leftTileCoord];
CGPoint bTileCoord = [self tileCoordForPosition:bottomTileCoord];
CGPoint rTileCoord = [self tileCoordForPosition:rightTileCoord];
CGPoint tTileCoord = [self tileCoordForPosition:topTileCoord];

if ([self isValidTileCoord:cTileCoord] && ![self isWallAtTileCoord:cTileCoord])
{
    [self addChild:circle0];
}
if ([self isValidTileCoord:lTileCoord] && ![self isWallAtTileCoord:lTileCoord])
{
    [self addChild:circle1];
    if (explosionLenght >= 2)
    {
        CCSprite *circle = [[CCSprite alloc]initWithFile:@"Circle.png"];
        circle.position = ccp(circle1.position.x - tileSize * 1, circle1.position.y);
        [self addChild:circle];
        id fade = [CCSequence actionOne:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1 position:circle.position] two:[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:1 scale:0]];
        [circle runAction:fade];
        if (explosionLenght >= 3)
        {
            CCSprite *circle = [[CCSprite alloc]initWithFile:@"Circle.png"];
            circle.position = ccp(circle1.position.x - tileSize * 2, circle1.position.y);
            [self addChild:circle];
            id fade = [CCSequence actionOne:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1 position:circle.position] two:[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:1 scale:0]];
            [circle runAction:fade];
            if (explosionLenght >= 4)
            {
                CCSprite *circle = [[CCSprite alloc]initWithFile:@"Circle.png"];
                circle.position = ccp(circle1.position.x - tileSize * 3, circle1.position.y);
                [self addChild:circle];
                id fade = [CCSequence actionOne:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1 position:circle.position] two:[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:1 scale:0]];
                [circle runAction:fade];
                if (explosionLenght >= 5)
                {
                    CCSprite *circle = [[CCSprite alloc]initWithFile:@"Circle.png"];
                    circle.position = ccp(circle1.position.x - tileSize * 4, circle1.position.y);
                    [self addChild:circle];
                    id fade = [CCSequence actionOne:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1 position:circle.position] two:[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:1 scale:0]];
                    [circle runAction:fade];
                    if (explosionLenght >= 6)
                    {
                        CCSprite *circle = [[CCSprite alloc]initWithFile:@"Circle.png"];
                        circle.position = ccp(circle1.position.x - tileSize * 5, circle1.position.y);
                        [self addChild:circle];
                        id fade = [CCSequence actionOne:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1 position:circle.position] two:[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:1 scale:0]];
                        [circle runAction:fade];
                        if (explosionLenght >= 7)
                        {
                            CCSprite *circle = [[CCSprite alloc]initWithFile:@"Circle.png"];
                            circle.position = ccp(circle1.position.x - tileSize * 6, circle1.position.y);
                            [self addChild:circle];
                            id fade = [CCSequence actionOne:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1 position:circle.position] two:[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:1 scale:0]];
                            [circle runAction:fade];
                            if (explosionLenght >= 8)
                            {
                                explosionLenght = 1;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }






}
if ([self isValidTileCoord:bTileCoord] && ![self isWallAtTileCoord:bTileCoord])
{
    [self addChild:circle3];
    if (explosionLenght >= 2)
    {
        CCSprite *circle = [[CCSprite alloc]initWithFile:@"Circle.png"];
        circle.position = ccp(circle3.position.x , circle3.position.y- tileSize * 1);
        [self addChild:circle];
        id fade = [CCSequence actionOne:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1 position:circle.position] two:[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:1 scale:0]];
        [circle runAction:fade];
        if (explosionLenght >= 3)
        {
            CCSprite *circle = [[CCSprite alloc]initWithFile:@"Circle.png"];
            circle.position = ccp(circle3.position.x, circle3.position.y - tileSize * 2);
            [self addChild:circle];
            id fade = [CCSequence actionOne:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1 position:circle.position] two:[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:1 scale:0]];
            [circle runAction:fade];
            if (explosionLenght >= 4)
            {
                CCSprite *circle = [[CCSprite alloc]initWithFile:@"Circle.png"];
                circle.position = ccp(circle3.position.x, circle3.position.y - tileSize * 3);
                [self addChild:circle];
                id fade = [CCSequence actionOne:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1 position:circle.position] two:[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:1 scale:0]];
                [circle runAction:fade];
                if (explosionLenght >= 5)
                {
                    CCSprite *circle = [[CCSprite alloc]initWithFile:@"Circle.png"];
                    circle.position = ccp(circle3.position.x, circle3.position.y - tileSize * 4);
                    [self addChild:circle];
                    id fade = [CCSequence actionOne:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1 position:circle.position] two:[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:1 scale:0]];
                    [circle runAction:fade];
                    if (explosionLenght >= 6)
                    {
                        CCSprite *circle = [[CCSprite alloc]initWithFile:@"Circle.png"];
                        circle.position = ccp(circle3.position.x, circle3.position.y - tileSize * 5);
                        [self addChild:circle];
                        id fade = [CCSequence actionOne:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1 position:circle.position] two:[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:1 scale:0]];
                        [circle runAction:fade];
                        if (explosionLenght >= 7)
                        {
                            CCSprite *circle = [[CCSprite alloc]initWithFile:@"Circle.png"];
                            circle.position = ccp(circle3.position.x , circle3.position.y- tileSize * 6);
                            [self addChild:circle];
                            id fade = [CCSequence actionOne:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1 position:circle.position] two:[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:1 scale:0]];
                            [circle runAction:fade];
                            if (explosionLenght >= 8)
                            {
                                explosionLenght = 1;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }


}
if ([self isValidTileCoord:rTileCoord] && ![self isWallAtTileCoord:rTileCoord])
{
    [self addChild:circle2];
    if (explosionLenght >= 2)
    {
        CCSprite *circle = [[CCSprite alloc]initWithFile:@"Circle.png"];
        circle.position = ccp(circle2.position.x + tileSize * 1, circle2.position.y);
        [self addChild:circle];
        id fade = [CCSequence actionOne:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1 position:circle.position] two:[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:1 scale:0]];
        [circle runAction:fade];
        if (explosionLenght >= 3)
        {
            CCSprite *circle = [[CCSprite alloc]initWithFile:@"Circle.png"];
            circle.position = ccp(circle2.position.x + tileSize * 2, circle2.position.y);
            [self addChild:circle];
            id fade = [CCSequence actionOne:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1 position:circle.position] two:[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:1 scale:0]];
            [circle runAction:fade];
            if (explosionLenght >= 4)
            {
                CCSprite *circle = [[CCSprite alloc]initWithFile:@"Circle.png"];
                circle.position = ccp(circle2.position.x + tileSize * 3, circle2.position.y);
                [self addChild:circle];
                id fade = [CCSequence actionOne:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1 position:circle.position] two:[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:1 scale:0]];
                [circle runAction:fade];
                if (explosionLenght >= 5)
                {
                    CCSprite *circle = [[CCSprite alloc]initWithFile:@"Circle.png"];
                    circle.position = ccp(circle2.position.x + tileSize * 4, circle2.position.y);
                    [self addChild:circle];
                    id fade = [CCSequence actionOne:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1 position:circle.position] two:[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:1 scale:0]];
                    [circle runAction:fade];
                    if (explosionLenght >= 6)
                    {
                        CCSprite *circle = [[CCSprite alloc]initWithFile:@"Circle.png"];
                        circle.position = ccp(circle2.position.x + tileSize * 5, circle2.position.y);
                        [self addChild:circle];
                        id fade = [CCSequence actionOne:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1 position:circle.position] two:[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:1 scale:0]];
                        [circle runAction:fade];
                        if (explosionLenght >= 7)
                        {
                            CCSprite *circle = [[CCSprite alloc]initWithFile:@"Circle.png"];
                            circle.position = ccp(circle2.position.x + tileSize * 6, circle2.position.y);
                            [self addChild:circle];
                            id fade = [CCSequence actionOne:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1 position:circle.position] two:[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:1 scale:0]];
                            [circle runAction:fade];
                            if (explosionLenght >= 8)
                            {
                                explosionLenght = 1;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
if ([self isValidTileCoord:tTileCoord] && ![self isWallAtTileCoord:tTileCoord])
{
    [self addChild:circle4];
    if (explosionLenght >= 2)
    {
        CCSprite *circle = [[CCSprite alloc]initWithFile:@"Circle.png"];
        circle.position = ccp(circle4.position.x , circle4.position.y+ tileSize * 1);
        [self addChild:circle];
        id fade = [CCSequence actionOne:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1 position:circle.position] two:[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:1 scale:0]];
        [circle runAction:fade];
        if (explosionLenght >= 3)
        {
            CCSprite *circle = [[CCSprite alloc]initWithFile:@"Circle.png"];
            circle.position = ccp(circle4.position.x, circle4.position.y + tileSize * 2);
            [self addChild:circle];
            id fade = [CCSequence actionOne:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1 position:circle.position] two:[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:1 scale:0]];
            [circle runAction:fade];
            if (explosionLenght >= 4)
            {
                CCSprite *circle = [[CCSprite alloc]initWithFile:@"Circle.png"];
                circle.position = ccp(circle4.position.x, circle4.position.y + tileSize * 3);
                [self addChild:circle];
                id fade = [CCSequence actionOne:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1 position:circle.position] two:[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:1 scale:0]];
                [circle runAction:fade];
                if (explosionLenght >= 5)
                {
                    CCSprite *circle = [[CCSprite alloc]initWithFile:@"Circle.png"];
                    circle.position = ccp(circle4.position.x, circle4.position.y + tileSize * 4);
                    [self addChild:circle];
                    id fade = [CCSequence actionOne:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1 position:circle.position] two:[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:1 scale:0]];
                    [circle runAction:fade];
                    if (explosionLenght >= 6)
                    {
                        CCSprite *circle = [[CCSprite alloc]initWithFile:@"Circle.png"];
                        circle.position = ccp(circle4.position.x, circle4.position.y + tileSize * 5);
                        [self addChild:circle];
                        id fade = [CCSequence actionOne:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1 position:circle.position] two:[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:1 scale:0]];
                        [circle runAction:fade];
                        if (explosionLenght >= 7)
                        {
                            CCSprite *circle = [[CCSprite alloc]initWithFile:@"Circle.png"];
                            circle.position = ccp(circle4.position.x , circle4.position.y- tileSize * 6);
                            [self addChild:circle];
                            id fade = [CCSequence actionOne:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1 position:circle.position] two:[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:1 scale:0]];
                            [circle runAction:fade];
                            if (explosionLenght >= 8)
                            {
                                explosionLenght = 1;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}

int waitTime = 1;
int shrinkTime = 1;


id circle0done = [CCSequence actionOne:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:waitTime position:c0TileCoord] two:[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:shrinkTime scale:0]];
id circle1done = [CCSequence actionOne:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:waitTime position:c1TileCoord] two:[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:shrinkTime scale:0]];
id circle2done = [CCSequence actionOne:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:waitTime position:c2TileCoord] two:[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:shrinkTime scale:0]];
id circle3done = [CCSequence actionOne:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:waitTime position:c3TileCoord] two:[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:shrinkTime scale:0]];
id circle4done = [CCSequence actionOne:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:waitTime position:c4TileCoord] two:[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:shrinkTime scale:0]];



[circle0 runAction:circle0done];
[circle1 runAction:circle1done];
[circle2 runAction:circle2done];
[circle3 runAction:circle3done];
[circle4 runAction:circle4done];
```

Comment: You could replace the enumerated variables by an array, e.g. `CCSprint **circles`. The giant `if`-cascades can be replaced by a loop from `2` to `explosionLength`; bound checking happens in the first few lines, so don't repeat it with the `>= 7` and `>= 8` tests which cannot return true (?). Once you have rewritten the code to use loops, further simplifications will present themselves.

Comment: `for`loops! So simple! Why didn't I think of that. Will implement, thanks. @amon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For someone who of some weird reason needs to do the same thing, here's the code I ended up using.

```
    -(void)explosionFromPoint:(CGPoint)explosionPoint withSprite:(CCSprite*)sprite;
{
    //int 
    explosionLenght += 1;
    if (explosionLenght >= 7) //Just for testing purposes, don't have a way to increase it naturally. 
    {
        explosionLenght = 1;
    }

    BOOL topB = YES;
    BOOL leftB = YES;
    BOOL bottomB = YES;
    BOOL rightB = YES;

    int bombX =    (explosionPoint.x + 1);
    int bombY =    (explosionPoint.y + 1);
    int bombNegX = (explosionPoint.x - 1);
    int bombNegY = (explosionPoint.y - 1);

    CGPoint top = ccp(explosionPoint.x, bombY);
    CGPoint left = ccp(bombNegX, explosionPoint.y);
    CGPoint bottom = ccp(explosionPoint.x, bombNegY);
    CGPoint right = ccp(bombX, explosionPoint.y);

    if (![self isLocationBombable:top])
    {topB = NO;}
    if (![self isLocationBombable:left])
    {leftB = NO;}
    if (![self isLocationBombable:bottom])
    {bottomB = NO;}
    if (![self isLocationBombable:right])
    {rightB = NO;}

    for (int i = 0; i <= explosionLenght; i++) {

        int bombX =    (explosionPoint.x + i);
        int bombY =    (explosionPoint.y + i);
        int bombNegX = (explosionPoint.x - i);
        int bombNegY = (explosionPoint.y - i);

        CGPoint top = ccp(explosionPoint.x, bombY);
        CGPoint left = ccp(bombNegX, explosionPoint.y);
        CGPoint bottom = ccp(explosionPoint.x, bombNegY);
        CGPoint right = ccp(bombX, explosionPoint.y);

        CCSprite *circleTop    = [[CCSprite alloc]initWithFile:@"Circle.png"];
        CCSprite *circleLeft   = [[CCSprite alloc]initWithFile:@"Circle.png"];
        CCSprite *circleBottom = [[CCSprite alloc]initWithFile:@"Circle.png"];
        CCSprite *circleRight  = [[CCSprite alloc]initWithFile:@"Circle.png"];

        if ([self isLocationBombable:top] && topB == YES)
        {
            circleTop.position = [self positionForTileCoord:top];
            [self addChild:circleTop];
            id fadeTop = [CCSequence actionOne:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1 position:circleTop.position] two:[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:1 scale:0]];
            [circleTop runAction:fadeTop];
        }
        if ([self isLocationBombable:left] && leftB == YES)
        {
            circleLeft.position = [self positionForTileCoord:left];
            [self addChild:circleLeft];
            id fadeLeft = [CCSequence actionOne:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1 position:circleLeft.position] two:[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:1 scale:0]];
            [circleLeft runAction:fadeLeft];
        }
        if ([self isLocationBombable:bottom] && bottomB == YES)
        {
            circleBottom.position = [self positionForTileCoord:bottom];
            [self addChild:circleBottom];
            id fadeBottom = [CCSequence actionOne:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1 position:circleBottom.position] two:[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:1 scale:0]];
            [circleBottom runAction:fadeBottom];
        }
        if ([self isLocationBombable:right] && rightB == YES)
        {
            circleRight.position = [self positionForTileCoord:right];
            [self addChild:circleRight];
            id fadeRight = [CCSequence actionOne:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1 position:circleRight.position] two:[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:1 scale:0]];
            [circleRight runAction:fadeRight];
        }
    }

    [currentBombs addObject:sprite];

    NSLog(@"Explosion done, call checkdamage");

    [self schedule:@selector(checkDamageForBomb)];
    [self performSelector:@selector(removeSprite:) withObject:sprite afterDelay:3];
}
```

Comment: Feel free to comment about further improvements to this code.